# How to Integrate spark bot with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

To integrate Spark with Jenkins I need to use Bearer Token of particular user(example User name ABC). So that Jenkins will send the notification with that user name (ABC).

I would like to use the Bearer Token of any bot instead of any user. So please help me to setup bot Bearer Token to Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developer.webex.com/add-bot.html and in this page u will get option to create new bot.
[Create Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpWTX.png) 
once bot is created, click on bot, here we can see bots access token, Copy it.

[Bot token page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI2hK.png)